# Strategy Pattern on Grails

Tags: grails, strategy-pattern

On my current task i have to calculate ideal 
This price is calculated by taking all the prices of this product, removing the 2 highest and 2 lowest, then doing an average with the rest and adding 20% to it.

I have my domain class

```
class Product { 
  String store
  String product_code
  int price
  String notes..........
```

Its posible to calculate the ideal price using strategy pattern?

[image]

How the value ends in the view ?... When the controller work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, Grails won't stop you from using the strategy pattern. Here's the basic *strategy*:

```
def prices = Product.withCriteria {
    projections {
        property 'price'
    }
}

def remaining = prices - prices.take(2) - prices.takeRight(2)
def ideal = remaining.sum() / remaining.size() * 1.2
```

So it amounts to a [GORM query](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-select-clause/) to get the prices, some GDK [Iterable](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html) methods, and math. You can certainly bundle that up into a strategy pattern, which BTW can be done in Groovy with Closures; you don't need to go the traditional route with interfaces and such:

```
def idealPriceStrategy = { prices ->
    def remaining = prices - prices.take(2) - prices.takeRight(2)

    return remaining.sum() / remaining.size() * 1.2
}

def myStrategy = idealPriceStrategy
def ideal = myStrategy(prices)
```

Comment: Nice solution , i added a sort in criteria